# Existence of continuous function (Calc I)

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

> Does there exist a continuous function $f(x)$ such that $f(0)=-7, f(2)=5$ and $f\;'(x)\leq-9$ for all $x$ in $(0,2)$?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. How do I check whether it's continuous or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use mean value theorem 
$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ for some $c$ in $(a,b)$

When you say "**it** is not continuous" in your comment, which function do you refer to ?

Suppose there were such a function $f$ that is continuous, at least on the closed interval $[a,b]=[0,2]$. Suppose the derivative exists at least on the open interval $(a,b)=(0,2)$, and that $f'(x)\le-9$ for all $x$ in $(0,2)$. But, then the MVT gives you that $f'(c)=6$, for some $c$ in $(0,2)$. This is a contradiction. The conclusion is not that "it is not continuous", the conclusion is that such a function does not exist.

Comment: So $\dfrac{5-(-7)}{2-0}=6$?

Comment: So it's not continuous?

Comment: @user437158 So the Mean Value Theorem says that if a function $f$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ and differentiable on $(0,2)$, then there is some point $c$ with $0< c< 2$ and $f'(c) = \frac{f(2) - f(0)}{2 - 0} = 6$.  But the problem asks if we can have a continuous function $f$ such that $f'(x) \leq -9$ for all $x$ in $(0,2)$... According to the Mean Value Theorem, we can't because **for every continuous function** there *has* to be some $c$ in $(0,2)$ with $f'(c) = 6$, and $6$ is not less than or equal to $-9$.